# Siteminder Policy Server 12.5 installation issues on windows server 2012

Tags: java, single-sign-on, siteminder

Has anyone successfully installed Siteminder Policy Sever 12.5 (or 12.x) on Windows Server 2012. Getting the following error:

```
D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\bin>java com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.SmConsole -smd
ir "D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder"
Couldn't load javasmconsoleapi
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.netegrity.sm.smco
nsole.services.SmConsoleAPI.java_api_init()Z
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.services.SmConsoleAPI.java_api_init(Native
Method)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.services.SmConsoleAPI.init(SmConsoleAPI.ja
va:60)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.ServerConnection.create(ServerConnection.j
ava:39)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.SettingsBean.<init>(SettingsBean.java:28)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.SmConsoleImpl.initSettings(SmConsoleImpl.j
ava:544)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.SmConsoleImpl.<init>(SmConsoleImpl.java:55
)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.SmConsoleImpl.main(SmConsoleImpl.java:47)
      at com.netegrity.sm.smconsole.SmConsole.main(SmConsole.java:19)
```

The env variables are as follows:

```
NETEGRITY_LICENSE_FILE=D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\license\license.dat
NETE_DOC_ROOT=D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\netegrity_documents
NETE_JAVA_PATH=D:\jdk_17\jre\bin;D:\jdk_17\jre\bin\server
NETE_JDK_ROOT=D:\jdk_17
NETE_JRE_ROOT=D:\jdk_17\jre
NETE_JVM_OPTION_FILE=D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\config\JVMOptions.txt
NETE_PS_OPACK="INSTALLED"
NETE_PS_PATH=D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\bin; D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\bin\thirdparty;D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder\lib
NETE_PS_ROOT=D:\ca\policyserver\siteminder
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use 64 bi java version with 32 bit policy server. Try using 32 bit java and set that path in the env.